# Why does my git shell look like this on my laptop: [name@name-Laptop ~ (master *+)]$, but not on desktop

Tags: bash, git

On my desktop, git looks like this: [image: Correct Git (What I want)]

On my laptop, git looks like this: `[name@name-Laptop ~ (master *+)]$`.

Here is an image to get a better idea of what git looks like on my laptop: [image: Incorrect Git (What I do not want)]

I have uninstalled and reinstalled git on my laptop, but after doing a normal setup as stated by multiple videos git always ends up as shown in the Incorrect Git.jpg file. How do I get git on my laptop to look like git on my desktop (Correct Git.jpg). I am using the VIM editor for both.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a matter of having the same shell configuration on both machines, not an issue with Git itself.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I will look at the configuration files in both machines.

Comment: Check the value of PS1.  eg, `echo "$PS1"`

Comment: Thank you for hinting the PS1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export PS1='\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$'` is the solution.

So I found out that the PS1 was to configure the editor as William Pursell mentioned in the comments above. My configuration before was set up as [\u@\h \W$(_git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$. This gave me that white text for everything in git bash as shown above. By changing the PS1 to the configuration in my answer, I was able to get the colorful setup, shown above, for git bash on my laptop. I was able to get that long configuration by using echo "$PS1" and copied that over to my laptop. It looks much cleaner to me and is able to make navigation much easier. Also, thank you for the welcome!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, ntrix. A bit more details would be much appreciated, but in any case thank you for the useful contribution!

Comment: this belongs in your answer, not in a comment, but way to go!

Comment: Okay. I fixed it. :). Thanks!